# Cross-correlation of two autocorrelated signals (removing autocorrelation with ARIMA)

Tags: r, arima, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I want to get the cross-correlation of two time series `x` and `y` in R.

I have calculated an ARIMA model, and I can get the `mod1$residuals` from signal `x`. These residuals almost have no autocorrelation, so that's great.

```
xts <- ts(x,start=1,frequency=12) #convert to a time series
library(fpp)  #load forecasting package
mod1 <- auto.arima(xts)
```

I now did the same procedure on signal `y`.

My question is: is this correct? Or should I somehow deduct the `mod1` (based on `x`) from `y` to de-trend it?

```
ccf(mod1$residuals, mod2$residuals)
```

Secondly, I am confused about the order of operations. Should I prewhiten the data before calculating the model?

I found this code:

```
prewhiten(x, y, x.model = ar.res,ylab="CCF", ...)
```

Should I estimate the `mod1` first and then supply it to the function `prewhiten`? And are `x` and `y` the two time series? Many thanks!

Comment: Related to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191131/testing-significance-of-cross-correlated-series/).

Comment: I don't fully understand the answer you point to. Do I remove the arima model from both time series? And do I remove the same model or make two models?

Comment: I know I did not manage to provide a clarification there; I posted the link so that other users could see the background of the question.

Comment: Regarding terminology, you "estimate" rather than "calculate" model `mod1` or ARIMA model. It could be nice to have this fixed in both your question and your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prewhitening seems like a good way to help interpret ccf. (see [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75))

Prewhitening basically estimates a model (such as ARIMA) on data1, then the residuals data2 and this model are used in a ccf function with data1 residuals. In the case of this question:

```
 print(prewhiten(y, model=mod1))
```

will display the ccf graph